# Selenium, ensure that all the checkbox are checked

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using Selenium to test action on a html page. The one i'm working on contains multiple list of check box. My selenium script do the following actions :
-Click on the dropdown list to display the check box list

-Click on all the check box

-Click on the dropdown list to close the check box list

-Repeat for the next list

The problem is that somtimes the script goes too fast for the browser and some box are not checked, it happens really often since i make multiple test 
To resolve my problem i tried to make a method that check if the 
checkbox is checked, if not then i click again but it's  not working and it increases the time of my test. Here my code so far :

```
    public void clickClearanceListBox(int numberInList) throws InterruptedException {
    int iteration = countTheNumberOfElement("//div[5]/div["+numberInList+"]/div[2]");

    for(int i = 1; i <= iteration; i++) {
        String xpathBox ="//div["+numberInList+"]/div[2]/div["+i+"]/div/div/label/span/span[2]";//xpath de la checkbox
        String xpathInput = "//div["+numberInList+"]/div[2]/div["+i+"]/div/div/label/input";

        clickTheDOMbyJs(xpathBox);

        while(!checkBoxChecked(xpathInput)) {
            Thread.sleep(200);
            clickTheDOMbyJs(xpathBox);
        }
    }
}
```

Or :

```
    public void clickClearanceListBox(int numberInList) throws InterruptedException {
    int iteration = countTheNumberOfElement("//div[5]/div["+numberInList+"]/div[2]");

    for(int i = 1; i <= iteration; i++) {
        String xpathBox ="//div["+numberInList+"]/div[2]/div["+i+"]/div/div/label/span/span[2]";//xpath de la checkbox
        String xpathInput = "//div["+numberInList+"]/div[2]/div["+i+"]/div/div/label/input";

        clickTheDOMbyJs(xpathBox);

        while(!checkBoxChecked(xpathInput)) {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the method implementation of checkBoxChecked

Comment: I don't suppose that you can share the page with us? I'd like to take a look at it. Do you know how many checkboxes there are supposed to be or is the number dynamic? You need to find a way to determine when the entire list is displayed, wait for that trigger, and then check all the boxes.

Comment: i can't share it isn' online sry,
 the number of checkbox is dynamic, but i can have the number i will try what you said jeffC,
the code of checkBoxChecked simply return true or false if the box is checked no need to provide it, it isn't revealing.

Comment: I get that you can't share the web page itself, but perhaps an HTML snippet of the page that has the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do it by checking if the attribute "value" of my checkbox has the value "true". While the attribute value is false, it means that the checkbox is still not checked for the browser so i wait... This extremly slow but at least it's working everytime. After  the script clicked on the checkbox i do this :

```
while(!getAnElementAttribute(xpathInput, "value").equals("true")) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use WebDriverWait in here.  First, wait for the dropdown list to load completely, then wait for the checkbox to be visible.

A word of warning to you though.  These xpaths are likely to be very brittle, and your tests will break quite easily.  You should consider finding these various elements using ids, classes, or other attributes.

Comment: thanks for the answer,  i can't use id since they are generated dynamically, i already wait for the checkboxlist to be totally loaded, and the checkbox to be visible but the things is that when my script click on the check box the browser take too much time to apply this action, then my script detect that the checkbox is still empty so it send the signal to reclick on the checkbox, but by this time the browser finally click on the checkbox so it receives the second click from the script and uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: Ah!  then your reclick action should not be done.  throw that out.  So you really want a call to WebDriverWait.until() for the checkbox to be visible, then another WebDriverWait.until() call for whatever the action is that checking that box will do.

Comment: yes, i tried this in the past, the problem is when i wait for the checkbox to be visible ihave a SteleReferenceElementException.

Comment: That's probably a cue that the page has been refreshed.  It sounds like the logic in that scenario needs a little tweaking.  It might be worthwhile opening a new thread for help with that, just so that it's not confused with this thread.